# HTML5 input attributes, access via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

as you might know, within the *HTML5 spec* we got some new attributes for `<input>` elements, such as `required` and `pattern`. This provides as a great way of validating user-input and we can even visualize it using *CSS* and *pseudo selectors*. Example

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d+" required/>
```

**CSS**

```
input:required:valid {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

input:required:invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If that `<input>` element would be part of an `<form>` element, an user wouldn't be able to submit that in `invalid state`.

However, my question is, what if we want to use those new attributes without `<form>` elements ? Is there a way to access the **current state** of such an `<input>` node through ECMAscript directly ?

Any event ? Any listener ?

Comment: Just doublechecking; With `current state`, you mean a JS way to check the validity of the input (As a property instead of a function you'd have to write)?

Comment: This is an interesting question - my (slight) research into the HTML5 form stuff suggested to me that it was designed under a philosophy of independence from scripting languages.  You can read the "validity state" via the `validityState` property, but I don't know whether being outside a `<form>` breaks anything.

Comment: [This MDN Forms Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation) has everything you need.

Comment: It's `validity` not `validityState`, sorry.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Zirak](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7431516#7431516), there is the [`checkValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation_API) method, part of the [Constraint Validation API](http://developers.whatwg.org/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api).

```
var s = document.createElement('input');
s.checkValidity(); // true
s.required = true;
s.checkValidity(); // false
```

However, `checkValidity` fires an invalid event if it's invalid. (The form will be red-outlined.) You may want to use the `willValidate` property (or the `.validity.valid` property) instead.

Also, the `validity` property is quite interesting to watch (more information about what each property means on the [Constraint Validation API](http://developers.whatwg.org/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api)):

```
s.validity
    ValidityState
        customError: false
        patternMismatch: false
        rangeOverflow: false
        rangeUnderflow: false
        stepMismatch: false
        tooLong: false
        typeMismatch: false
        valid: false
        valueMissing: true
```

This article points out the differences in implementations between the browsers: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/ (i.e: it's a mess, as usual.)

You can also listen to the [`invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/invalid) event, triggered on submit of the form, or when the `checkValidity` method is called.

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/XfV4z/

Comment: Yea hail @Zirak. I'll just do some browser compat tests right now.

Comment: I beat you to the `validity` property :P

Comment: Zirak will haunt you in your dreams for that stolen rep!

Comment: @GNi33, he'll have to get in line. Grrrrr.
Still, it helps that a high-rep user adds `validity` to his answer, also :P An a different note: _"(i.e: it's..."_ I see what you did there.

Comment: Seems to worky pretty reliably across supporting browsers. (I added the fiddle to the answer) +1

Comment: Infact you even have the eventlistener `invalid` that triggers on invalidity.

Comment: @Christoph is it triggered `oninput`, `onsubmit`, or something else? I can't find any documentation about this.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks! Added this to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The input elements have a `validity` property:

```
var i = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
i.validity.valid // True or false

console.log(i.validity);

// Logs (when `1` is entered):

 ValidityState
   customError: false
   patternMismatch: false
   rangeOverflow: false
   rangeUnderflow: false
   stepMismatch: false
   tooLong: false
   typeMismatch: false
   valid: true
   valueMissing: false
```

For more detailed info I'm not going to copy, check [Florian Margaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851498/florian-margaine)['s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14585861/1835379)

Comment: Could the person that downvoted me please tell me why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it. Honestly, `-2`?, What's with the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote, because this is good information, but I *think* that the property may be "validityState" and not just "validity". *edit* nope I'm wrong, it's `validity` :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Google Chrome tells me it's `validity`. (I always test my code before answering)

Comment: @Pointy the property is `validity`, but the constructor object is `ValidityState` :-)